# Event handling on drawn image

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios-simulator

Can any body support me with good examples of codes in iphone app how the event handling can be performed in specific task on touch event..

for example I had drawn different point(dot image in png format) located on different portion around the iphone screen using Quartz 2d framework and I need to handle event on touching these point(dot image in png format) drawn with respect to touch actions perform in that points(dot image in png format).

Could you guys provide me any good approches to start these kinds of event.

Thanking you....:)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate? U are drawing images on uiview using Quartz 2D and you want to capture those images with touches??

If this is the case, dont use quartz2d instead go for CALayers and there you can get which CALayer was touched. 
But this may be a costlier approach if you are using multiple of images loaded.

Comment: Yes I am using UIView using Quartz 2d, I had plotted the dot.png file in screen and I want touch effect event when we trigger tap on screen just like mouse over action on windows platform. Is this possible and feasible in this graphics framework?? Or we have another better approaches to have it like u suggest me to go with CALayers. Could u please confirm about this?

Comment: No for graphics, I dont think so that you will be able to do that thing. Since in quartz2d, it draws your context and forget what is drawn. So U need to take another approach, How many images are you drawing??

Comment: I am using single png file but it had been plotted in different screen location with different coordintes. It almost at 13 places I plot that single image.

Comment: If that is 13 instances and not more, u can use single instance of image and plot it at variable positions

Comment: Ya I think I am doing like that...for example my code snippet is like this which use single image instatance..................[myImage drawAtPoint:imagePoint1];
 [myImage drawAtPoint:imagePoint2];
 [myImage drawAtPoint:imagePoint3];
 [myImage drawAtPoint:imagePoint4];
 ..........
 [myImage drawAtPoint:imagePoint11];
 [myImage drawAtPoint:imagePoint12];
 [myImage drawAtPoint:imagePoint13];
  
 [myImage release];

Comment: Okay then you can use CALayer instead of drawing on context

Comment: Hope this tutorial help you http://zearfoss.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/elastic-dragging-with-a-calayer/

Comment: Thank u so much, Obviously I will going thru this, hope it will help me to do this.. :)